# Trying to concatenate across records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a bit of a problem that I just can't seem to get my head round.  I've got a table that I'm trying to extract some data from.  Below is an example of the data.

```
Id  DevId     Route
1   1         1
2   1         2
3   1         3
4   1         4
5   2         1
6   2         2
```

What I want the result to look like would be:

```
DevId     Route
1         1234
2         12
```

Don't know if I've been looking at it for too long or something, but I just can't work out how to do it.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Create table ##tmp (id int, name int)
insert into ##tmp values(1,1)
insert into ##tmp values(1,2)
insert into ##tmp values(1,3)
insert into ##tmp values(2,1)
insert into ##tmp values(2,2)

Select   id, (Select cast (name as varchar(4)) 
            from    ##tmp t2
            where   t1.id = t2.id
            for xml path('')
            )
from ##tmp t1
group by id

drop table  ##tmp